# Is it harmful to use both early binding and late binding in the same C# .net 3.5 app?

Tags: c#, com, .net-3.5, late-binding, early-binding

We are having an intermittent/inconsistent problem whereby the Word COM reference (and other COM references as well) are not being recognized in the case of one user's machine on some SVN working copies and sometimes only for Debug. In those failure cases, the build fails, complaining of "resolvecomreference task failed unexpectedly". This is not unexpected, as VS2008 shows the yellow-triangle warning exclamation-point for each such item in the references list.

I have read numerous articles on this and a question arose. Our app uses a mix of some early-binding and some late-binding for calls to MSO (Microsoft Office). Could that be harmful?

These parts of the app have not changed in some time, and the problem is recent. Maybe, however, we have had an underlying potential bug all awhile?
thank you for any insights! I have little knowledge of the technical details in this area.